# How to use xdt transform to remove role:require attribute

Tags: configuration, patch-configuration

I am using xdt transforms to modify my Sitecore.config file for different environments.
I want to remove a `role:require="!ContentDelivery"` attribute.

I'm targeting the following element:

```
<databases>
  <!-- core -->
    <database id="core" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" role:require="!ContentDelivery">
```

and want to remove the `role:require="!ContentDelivery"` attribute.

If I use the following xdt syntax

```
<database id="core" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" xdt:Locator="Match(id)" xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(role:require)"/>
```

I get the error "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.".

If I omit the namespace prefix i.e.

```
<database id="core" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" xdt:Locator="Match(id)" xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(require)"/>
```

It doesn't work.

Is there a solution to this, or perhaps a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: In what conditions would the transform run? Would it be less complicated to use the patching system to override based on Environment variables? https://blog.vitaliitylyk.com/sitecore-environment-variables-config-builder/

Comment: It would run at project build/compile time to generate the output Sitecore.config file. Easier solution is to just modify Sitecore.config and remove that role:require attribute, but I wanted to try and avoid modifying Sitecore.config directly.

Answer (score 2):

`xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(role:require)"` should work correctly. But you need to remember to add `xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/"` attribute to the `<configuration>` tag of your tranform config file:

```
<configuration xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <databases>
    <database xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(role:require)" />
  </databases>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried this, but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Replace syntax:

```
<database id="core" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" xdt:Locator="Match(id)" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
```

You can find references to the details and another syntax: [Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Project Deployment Using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: I did get this technique to work, so this is sometimes a good solution, but in my case, I did not want to duplicate the whole database configuration elements.